# How to make long shared pointer initialization shorter

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I'm currently initializing an object like this (it will basically always have a long lifetime and be owned by multiple objects):

```
std::shared_ptr<framework::Actor> actor (new framework::Actor());
```

How can I make this shorter without using a function to initialize it? Other classes should be able to extend the actor and still be "easily" initializable

Comment: Define "shorter".

Comment: What's wrong with `auto actor = std::make_shared<framework::Actor>();`?

Comment: side note, whenever you are both constructing a `shared_ptr` and the object it will own, do it with `make_shared`. It will allocate the memory to hold your object and the memory for the reference counting at the same time so that there is one allocation instead of two. Also, they'll be next to each other in memory so the reference counter will almost always be cache-hot if you are using the object which is often an added bonus.

Comment: @RyanP Didn't think of that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

did you try to use "auto". Please find the reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto)